# SOAPClient PHP esta inserindo parametros indesejaveis

Tags: php, soap

estou precisando de uma ajuda.

estou tentando realizar uma comunicação entre uma pagina PHP e o SOAP de uma empresa terceirizada, mas ja testei diversas formas e não consigo resolver.

na hora de enviar o XML ele esta colocando Tags de forma automatica mesmo eu não inserindo no meu codigo.

o que pode ser?

abaixo exemplo dos codigos que estou trabalhando

```
   function atualizacaoCadastralXML(){

global $log, $client, $parceria, $connMS, $connSY;

$client = new SoapClient('http://cia-118:8080/g5-senior-services/rubi_Synccom_senior_g5_rh_fp_fichaComplementar?wsdl', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 0,
    'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
    'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT));


$user = 'nome.sobrenome';

$data = soapify(array(
    "user" => $user,
    'parameters' => array(
        'numcad' => '123456',
        'numemp' => 1,
        'TipOpe' => 'A',
        'TipCol' => 1
    ),
));

$method = 'FichaComplementar_7';

$result = $client->$method(new SoapParam($data, 'Data'));

echo "<pre>";
echo print_r(htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()));
echo "</pre>";
die();
}

function soapify(array $data){

    foreach ($data as &$value){ 
        if (is_array($value)){ 
            $value = soapify($value);
        }
    }    
        return new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
}
```

O retorno do codigo acima é o seguinte, notem quem em nenhum momento eu passo algo relacionado ao user, password e encritpion.

```
<?
 xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
 xmlns:ns1="http://services.senior.com.br">
 <env:Body>
     <ns1:FichaComplementar_7>
       <user>
          <user>nome.sobrenome</user>
          <parameters>
             <numcad>123456</numcad>
             <numemp>1</numemp>
             <TipOpe>A</TipOpe>
             <TipCol>1</TipCol>
     </parameters>
     </user><password/>
     <encryption/>
     <parameters/>
     </ns1:FichaComplementar_7>
 </env:Body>
 </env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sua função `soapify` está bem estranha. Poderia revisá-la, por favor?

Comment: Oi Anderson, desculpe, estava faltando as "{ }" deve ter sido na hora de colar.